# Debian 7.3 can't remove postgresql

Tags: debian, package-management, dpkg

Solved:

I removed `/var/lib/dpkg/info/postgresql-8.4` 
Now everything is fine.

```
sudo rm -r /var/lib/dpkg/info/postgresq*
```

---

I got this problem:

```
alex@VRIL ~ % sudo apt-get install python3
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 postgresql-8.4 : Depends: postgresql-client-8.4 but it is not installable
                  Depends: postgresql-common (>= 109~) but it is not going to be installed
 postgresql-9.1 : Depends: postgresql-client-9.1 but it is not going to be installed
                  Depends: postgresql-common (>= 115~) but it is not going to be installed
 python3 : Depends: python3.2 (>= 3.2.3) but it is not going to be installed
           Depends: python3-minimal (= 3.2.3-6) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
100 alex@VRIL ~ %
```

I tried the following commands:

```
sudo apt-get install -f
sudo apt-get autoremove
sudo aptitude remove postgre*
sudo apt-get remove --purge postgres*
```

The problem is, i don't need postgres, I don't even know where it comes from ... but it prevents me from installing something.

if I do `sudo apt-get -f install` I get  this result:

```
/var/lib/dpkg/info/postgresql-8.4.prerm: 7: .: Can't open /usr/share/postgresql-common/maintscripts-functions
dpkg: error processing postgresql-8.4 (--remove):
 subprocess installed pre-removal script returned error exit status 2
Errors were encountered while processing:
 postgresql-8.4
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Any ideas?

Comment: You should post your solution as an answer to your own question (and accept it), so that it shows as solved in the listing

Comment: Users with less than 10 reputation can't answer their own question for 8 hours after asking. You can answer 12/15/2013 3:22:47 AM. Until then please use comments, or edit your question instead.